# Distance to the unit ball

Tags: analysis

I am currently reading a book on analysis. I have some finite dimensional Hilbert space $H$ and let $B$ be its unit ball. Then it says that the distance of some random point $x \in H$ to the unit ball is given by
$$
  d(x,B) = \max\{0, 1 - \| x \| \}.
$$
But shouldn't it be
$$
  d(x,B) = \max\{0, \| x \| - 1 \}?
$$
If $S_H$ is the unit sphere, then I have $d(x,S_H) = \max\{0,1 - \| x \|, \| x \| - 1 \}$.

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: you don't need a 0 in your last expression, but yes, the book most likely assumes that the point is inside the ball for whatever reason

Answer (score 1):

When the point is inside of the unit sphere $S_H$, then yes, the distance is given by $d(x,S_H)=\max\{0,1-\|x\|\}$. When the point is outside the unit sphere we have $d(x,S_H)=\max\{0,\|x\|-1\}$ as you've said.

Of course that means you are correct, since you are dealing with the unit ball, in which being inside the unit sphere gives us $d(x,B)=0$.